# update record, or delete and re-insert if the user edits their cart before processing the order

Tags: php, mysql, cart

I have a table named `orders_products` which hold all the products associated with each individual orders. Now, if the customer decides to edit the quantity, the attributes, or simply just remove a product, what would be the easiest way to handle this change in the database?

**orders_products**

```
id  |  quantity  |  fk_products_id  |  attributes  |  price  |  fk_orders_nr
```

`fk_products_id` refers to the actual product id in our products table
`attributes` is a comma sepparated string with id's refering to our attributes table (attributes can be the angle, lenght, diameter etc. for each product. As in 45 degres, left angeled, 20 cm in length, 43mm in diameter).
`fk_orders_nr` is the actual order the product belongs to.

Since I have a `class` that handles this part on the client side. Would it be easier to just `DELETE` all associated products, based on the order id (`fk_orders_nr`), and just re-insert and updated the whole set based on what's stored in the class?
Or is there a neat way to handle this directly in MySQL?

I've looked a bit into `on duplicate key update`, and `ignore`, but they doesn't seem to fit my needs..

I need to check to see if the actual product id exists, then decide to insert new, or update existing (it could be both the quantity, and/or optional attributes), also the product might be removed if not in the list from the `class` anymore.

*When writing this question. I think deleting the whole set, and reinsert it, might be the easiest way.*

Comment: Could you clarify by giving some of the DB structure?

Comment: can you make your question a little simpler

Comment: I've updated my question @Naruto.  What do you mean by "simpler" someone?

Comment: What is an attribute?

Comment: So orders_products is actually the in between table? Like Product - Orderline - Order ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This database looks badly designed. Firstly I assume by `fk_products_id` you mean `product_id`. You do not need to specify that a column is a foreign key in its name.

Secondly, I would advise you to keep all columns atomic, as in, no multi-values. The `attributes` column keeping a comma-separated list will give you headaches in the future and it also breaks the [FIRST normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) (the most basic one).

Thirdly, you don't need (although it could sometimes be useful) an `id` as a primary key in your junction table. You can just use a compound primary key from your `fk_products_id` and `fk_orders_nr` keys.

> When writing this question. I think deleting the whole set, and
>   reinsert it, might be the easiest way.

Yes, that is the way it's usually done.

But I **insist** you ignore everything about the current problem you're having and **redesign** your database from scratch, putting special attention into [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). These are **basic** database design standards and they exist for a reason. Hopefully you won't learn about the reason when it's too late.

Comment: I'm aware of the bad design part. But it won't be possible at this moment to redisign it. The firm want a redesign of the payment/order process, and not a database structure redesign... So I will have to work with this for now. But anyway, thanks for the advice..

Comment: @ThomasK Ahh I see. So were you only asking whether you should delete the whole set and reinsert it? If so, then yes.

Comment: Yup. That would be what I was wondering about. I too don't care much for the comma sepparated string either. It limits a lot of possibilities, and makes coding unnecessarily cumbersome... But it is what it is, and I have to adapt when writing the code.

Comment: @ThomasK I know what you mean, I've been there. Good luck